# Returning a list of numbers from a function in C using Struct

Tags: c, arrays, database, struct

I'm trying to solve this codewars [kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/k-primes/train/c)

Basically I need to wite a programe that spits out an `array/list` of numbers from a perticular range (of numbers) which have `k primes` multiplicatively.

```
countKprimes(5, 500, 600) --> [500, 520, 552, 567, 588, 592, 594]
```

Now my program "works" as in it can print the results correctly, but if I put it in codewars' answer area (without `main` of course), it just runs forever.

"Error code `SIGKILL` : Process was terminated. It took longer than 12000ms to complete"

This is the codewars template

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// In the preloaded section are some functions that can help.
// They can be used as a small library.
// There is no file to include, only the templates below.

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct list {
    size_t sz;
    struct node *head;
};

struct list* createList();

// push data at the head of the list
void insertFirst(struct list* l, int data);

struct list* reverse(struct list* l);

void listFree(struct list* l);

// functions to write
struct list* kPrimes(int k, int start, int nd)
{
    // your code
}
```

And this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct list{
    int a[600];
};

int smallestPrimeFactor(int number){
        int x;

        for(x = 2; x < number; x++) {
                if(number % x == 0) {
                        return x;
                }
        }
        return number;
}

int primefactors(int ofnumber){
        static int counter = 0;
        int tempcounter = counter;
        int nextnumber = ofnumber/smallestPrimeFactor(ofnumber);
        if(nextnumber != 1) {
                if(ofnumber >= nextnumber) {
                        counter++;
                        primefactors(nextnumber);
                }
        }
        return (counter - tempcounter) + 1;
}

struct list kPrimes(int k, int start, int nd){
    int x, g = 0;
    struct list ls;
    for(x = start; x < nd; x++){
        if(primefactors(x) == k){
            ls.a[g] = x;
            g++;
        }
    }
    return ls;
}

int main(int argc, int **argv){
    int p = 5, s = 500, e = 600;
    int j = 0;

    while(kPrimes(p, s, e).a[j] != '\0'){
        printf("%d\n", kPrimes(p, s, e).a[j]);
        j++;

    }
}
```

I think the culprit here is

```
struct list{
    int a[600];
};
```

Maybe while reading the array, the test file is overshooting a's index past `'\0'`.

I thought of a way of solving that by making `a` a pointer to integer but doing `int *a;` prints out nothing.

I know there are more than one way of returning an array. Using referance, using a static array, passing an array as argument, etc. But I want to solve this codewars' way. Think it'll be a nice learning experience.

So, how should I be using

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct list {
    size_t sz;
    struct node *head;
};
```

to solve the problem?

Comment: You should not bother about the structure themselves, you should just use `createList()`, `insertFirst()`, `reverse`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not bother about the structure themselves, you should simply use the provided functions:

```
struct list* kPrimes(int k, int start, int nd){
    int x, g = 0;
    struct list *ls = createList(); // 1. Create the list.
                                    // 2. Maybe check if ls != NULL...
    for(x = start; x < nd; x++){
        if(primefactors(x) == k){
            insertFirst(ls, x);     // 3. Insert at the beginning.
            g++;
        }
    }

    struct list *rls = reverse(ls); // 4. Reverse the list.
    listFree(ls);                   // 5. Free the original list.
    return rls;                     // 6. Return the reversed list.
}
```

Since the functions `reverse` is not documented, I can only guess that it creates a new list without modifying the old one, which is why you need to free it after.

Answer (score 0):

The `createList()`, `insertFirst()`, `reverse()`, and `listFree()` functions, as well as the function that consumes the return value of *your* function are all provided to you, and they all work with the types `struct list` and `struct node`.  How, then, do you imagine it could work if you try to use a differently-defined `struct list` than those existing functions use?

So yes, you should be using the `struct node` and `struct list` types provided to you -- and the handy functions for manipulating them -- rather than defining different structure types with the same tags.